# Gson custom deserializer for specific fields to String

Tags: java, gson, deserialization

I have a variety of JSON files (with slightly different schemas) flowing on Kinesis. Their Schema is really complex. They are user raw hits and their schema is super complex.  I would like to create a Single POJO to represent all underneath messages (Something Spark does internally by creating a Single schema). I was trying to use GSON library but the only way to accomplish this is, by writing a custom deserializer and in that case, I will end up writing deserialization logic for all the fields in those JSONs.
Is there any way where we can only overwrite the deserialization of a few fields only and the rest of the fields can still be deserialized by GSON as a default way?

```
JSON-1
{
   "first_col":"abc",
   "second_col":false
}

JSON-2
{
   "first_col":"abc",
   "second_col":"false-String"
}


JSON-3
{
   "first_col":"abc",
   "second_col":{
      "col1":"xyz",
      "col2":123
   }
}
```

Common POJO

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Example {

private String firstCol;

private String secondCol;

public String getFirstCol() {
return firstCol;
}

public void setFirstCol(String firstCol) {
this.firstCol = firstCol;
}

public Boolean getSecondCol() {
return secondCol;
}

public void setSecondCol(String secondCol) {
this.secondCol = secondCol;
}

}
```

So basically second_col could be boolean, string, or complex object. first_col is always a string. So I don't want to write deserialize logic for first_col. I want to write deserialize logic for only second_col and deserialize it to string only and the downstream consumer will take care of converting it to the right type before consuming this field.

Comment: Simply declare `second_col` as `JsonElement`, and then deserialize it correspondingly since it's polymorphic.

Comment: Thanks @fluffy, do you want me to declare it as JsonElment on POJO using annotations? or you want me to do it on custom Deserialization class? If later option is the right way then do I need to manually deserialize all fields ?  Sorry I am new to GSON lib.

Comment: No, no annotations (so far), simply change the type of the field to `JsonElement`. This would guarantee Gson to hold 100% accurate copy of your input JSON appearing in the "second column", so after the whole object is deserialized, your downstream consumer can take care of it. You _may_ want to implement a deserializer only if you have a defined type mapping that can handle cover all cases for the "second column" values.

Comment: Note that declaring it as `Object` may not work properly because of other deserializers that may take into place.

Comment: _If later option is the right way then do I need to manually deserialize all fields?_ Well, sort of. If you have a defined set of classes covering (all) possible cases -- then you can create a specific deserializer (and then either generalize them under a common type, or add the `@JsonAdapter` annotation, so that it would work). But again, if the number of possible values is large, having it as `JsonElement` may be the most straight-forward solution.